# Installing solidity on Sublime Text

Tags: solidity

I tried installing the solidity package onto sublime text. To make a long story short, its in the packages but my solidity is not responding the way my js code is. Meaning the functions are not colored the way it is with the other programming languages I have. I restarted the app twice now and nothing has changed, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

**Step -1**
In sublime go to View --> Console
Paste below and hit enter

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '817937144c34c84c88cd43b85318b2656f9c3fac02f8f72cbc18360b2c26d139'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

Step-2
Restart sublime
On your keyboard click Cmd + Shift + P
Type install and choose
Install Package
type Ethereum and you will come across 2 packages which need to be installed
Ethereum and EthereumSoliditySnippets

Step-3 once your finished installing the above 2 packages, restart sublime and you should be good to start using .sol files.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It was working the whole time, I just had a syntax error in typing the file